# MXMLC strange error: Error: only one source is allowed in the filespec

Tags: apache-flex, air, mxmlc

I'm trying to compile the simple AIR app from [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/quickstart/articles/interacting_with_native_process.html). I get a strange error, strange in that Googling it hardly reveals three results.

mxmlc -library-path=/Applications/Adobe Flash Builder Burrito/sdks/4.5.0/frameworks/libs/air/airglobal.swc NativeProcessTestFlex.mxml

Loading configuration file /Applications/Adobe Flash Builder Burrito/sdks/4.5.0/frameworks/flex-config.xml
Adobe Flex Compiler (mxmlc)
Version 4.5.0 build 17689
Copyright (c) 2004-2009 Adobe Systems, Inc. All rights reserved.

Error: only one source is allowed in the filespec

Use 'mxmlc -help' for information about using the command line.

Anyone knows what this error is all about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this instead:

```
mxmlc -library-path="/Applications/Adobe Flash Builder Burrito/sdks/4.5.0/frameworks/libs/air/airglobal.swc" NativeProcessTestFlex.mxml
```

You had spaces in the application name, which make the command line think it was the next 'parameter'.

Comment: I'm sure I tried that already and it didn't work :), anyway I get a different error now, probably related to having wrong swc, do you know what all I need to specify in the library-path? Error: Unable to locate specified base class 'spark.components.WindowedApplication' for component class 'NativeProcessTestFlex'.

Comment: @Ska you should use `adt` but not `mxmlc` for AIR apps as in your link.

Comment: @Constantiner but adt is asking for SWF, not mxml file, am I missing something? It's the first time I'm fiddling with both MXMLC and ADT.

Comment: @Constantiner also, the article in the link has adt ... NativeProcessTest-app.xml NativeProcessTest.swf, so I was thinking first I need to compile to get the SWF and then use ADT to package into AIR. Isn't that so?

Comment: Sorry for a mistake. You should use `amxmlc`. See [here for details](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f2012b5a4128cca83a39-8000.html#WS2d929364fa0b8137-4622b98b129dc3cff3f-8000)

Answer (score 4):

Try to place library path in quotes the following way:

```
mxmlc -library-path="/Applications/Adobe Flash Builder Burrito/sdks/4.5.0/frameworks/libs/air/airglobal.swc" NativeProcessTestFlex.mxml
```

The problem is definitely in spaces so it thinks `Flash` and `Builder` and `Burrito/sdks/4.5.0/frameworks/libs/air/airglobal.swc` are source files.