# Error: only one source is allowed in the filespec - Related SO answer does not work

Tags: apache-flex, mxmlc

I'm getting the following error, which works fine in Flash Builder 4.5 but does not work with Flex SDK

> C:\FlexSDK\bin>mxmlc -static-link-runtime-shared-libraries=false
>   -use-network=fa lse "C:\workspace\gui\Mill_UI.mxml" -output "C:\workspace\gui\out\op.swf"
>
> Loading configuration file
>   C:\FlexSDK\frameworks\flex-config.xml 
>   Loading configuration file> C:\workspace\gui\Mill_UI-config.xml Adobe Flex Compiler (mxmlc)
>   Version 4.6.0 build 23201 Copyright (c) 2004-2011 Adobe Systems, Inc.
>   All rights reserved.
>
> Error: only one source is allowed in the filespec
>
> Use 'mxmlc -help' for information about using the command line.
>
> C:\FlexSDK\bin>

I tried the remedy suggested for a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951753/mxmlc-strange-error-error-only-one-source-is-allowed-in-the-filespec), I added quotes,modified the folder structure so there are no spaces, but I still get the error

I also created a project specific config file using -dump-config and modified the paths as well but to no avail

Thanks !

Comment: There seems to be a space in the word `fa lse`. If this is an exact copy of your command, that will probably be the issue.

Comment: Oh, its not an exact copy. I don't have a space there in my command

Comment: Try adding an `=` between `-output` and the path.